# Multiple mySQL calls for comment section

Tags: php, mysql

Following a tutorial on youtube I did a simple "comment system" using php and mySQL. It works great, but just for one comment, if I make another comment, it shows up the last comment I made. Here's the code(I'm not including the form because it's not relevant here.):

PHP sendComment.php(action of index.php form):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("comments");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];

mysql_query("insert into comments values('','$name','$email','$comment')");
header("location: index.php");

?>
```

PHP OF index.php:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
    mysql_select_db("comments");

    $find_comments = mysql_query("select * from comments");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_comments)) {

            $comment_name = $row['name'];
            $comment_email = $row['email'];
            $comment = $row['comment'];

        }

?>
```

And finally, the comment:

```
<div class="comment">
    <h2><?php echo "$comment_name";?></h2>
    <p><?php echo "$comment";?></p>
</div>
```

How can I make that the comments stack up just like in facebook or so?.

PS: I understand the code in the tutorial, I have some knowledge in PHP and programming in general but I can't come up with a way to do this.

PS 2: I thought of using the comment ID to check for it and display the other elements in function of that ID. Is this the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code, you're always using same vars inside while loop to store comment content, so at the end you got only the last comment.

Instead, you can print each comment inside while loop:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("comments");

$find_comments = mysql_query("select * from comments");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_comments)) {
        ?>
        <div class="comment">
            <h2><?php echo $row['name'];?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['comment'];?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

?>
```